# Python Nested Dictionary results in {}

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a Kivy app that is filling in my spinnervalue, dateButton, and meatType. This filled my nested dictionary when I had something simple like this:

```
    def updateCart(self):
        self.cart[self.dateButton] = {self.meatType: self.spinnervalue}
```

So I know my Kivy app is filling my variables properly, but I need to add checks to this that will either update the value in the nested dictionary if the item is already in there or add the new item they tried to put in there. So I need to do some sort of a check for that kind of stuff. This is what I've tried so far:

```
    spinnervalue = ''
    dateButton = ''
    meatType = ''
    cart = {}

    def updateCart(self):
        for dates, meats in self.cart:
            if self.meatType == meats:
                print("already in cart")
            else:
                self.cart[self.dateButton] = {self.meatType: self.spinnervalue}
        print(self.cart)
```

The only thing this outputs is {}

For context, here is an image of the app: https://gyazo.com/4789cd96be9855d8341f2ae052061ed8

I just at this point do not know how to make this work to the point that keeps all my data grouped (the date, name of the meat, and quantity selected) to display and later input to my database.

Answer (score 0):

Couple things.

1. In your for loop you need to loop over `self.cart.items()` instead of `self.cart` which is just looping over the keys (this would blow up if you successfully added anything to the cart trying to unpack a string in to two things (dates and meats))
2. Since the cart is initially empty your actual assignment statement can't be within that for loop. Typically you'd do something like this:

```
for k, v in self.cart.items():
    if //some sort of check
        // some sort of error
// now add
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you might be easier off keying the cart dictionary with a tuple (or if you're feeling fancy, a `namedtuple`) of the date and the product type, to avoid the nesting.

```
cart = {}
cart[("2020-09-03", "Brisket")] = 1
```